# How can I tell if a sequence can be a recursive sequence

Tags: linear-algebra

Obviously 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, etc.. is possibly a recursive sequence because we know it's the Fibonacci sequence and because it's really easy to see the pattern. It's recursive "function" for the form $a(n_{i - 1}) + b (n_{i - 2})$ where $a = 1$ and $b = 1$.

But how do we know for sure that 1, 2, 3, 4, _, _, etc.. can't have a recursive function? where there is a $a$ or $b$ that works for that sequence?

Comment: Argh I don't know how to make more than one character go in a subscript can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: to make multiple subscript charachters you can do : normal text_{your subscript text} which gives: $$normal\ text_{your\ subscript\ text}$$ Place all characters inside brackets

Comment: Fancy, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into : [Solving homogeneous linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

We can easily find the solutions for this kind of linear recurrence relation:
If $x^2-ax-b = 0$ has 2 real solutions $r_1$ and $r_2$ then the sequence looks like : $u_n=A*r_1^n + B*r_2^n$

If $x^2-ax-b = 0$ has 1 real solution $r$ then the sequence looks like : $u_n=(n*A+B)*r^n $

If $x^2-ax-b = 0$ has 2 complex solutions $r_1$ and $r_2$ then the sequence looks like : $u_n=|r|^n*(A\cos(n\theta)+B\sin(n\theta))$ with $\theta = arg(r)$

As you can see there is always r^n which prevents linear sequences like $1,2,3,4,5...$ (except if $r = 1$)
In that case your characteristic polynomial looks like $(r-1)^2=0$, thus your recursive relation looks like $u_n=2u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}$
Also, you'll need $A = 1$ and $B = 0$.
that means $u_0=0$ and $u_1=1$

**Note:** I can make a more in depth answer but is is very well described in the article i have linked